# Error in ffmpeg when reading from UDP stream

Tags: c++, c, ffmpeg, udp, video-streaming

I'm trying to process frames from a UDP stream using ffmpeg. Everything will run fine for a while but `av_read_frame()` will always eventually return either `AVERROR_EXIT` (Immeditate exit requested) or `-5` (Error number -5 occurred) while the stream should still be running fine. Right before the error it always prints the following message to the console

```
[mpeg2video @ 0caf6600] ac-tex damaged at 14 10
[mpeg2video @ 0caf6600] Warning MVs not available
[mpeg2video @ 0caf6600] concealing 800 DC, 800 AC, 800 MV errors in I frame
```

(the numbers in the message vary from run to run)

I have a suspicion that the error is related to calling `av_read_frame` too quickly. If I have it run as fast as possible, I usually get an error within 10-20 frames, but if I put a sleep before reading it will run fine for a minute or so and then exit with an error. I realize this is hacky and assume there is a better solution. Bottom line: is there a way to dynamically check if 'av_read_frame()' is ready to be called? or a way to supress the error?

Psuedo code of what I'm doing below. Thanks in advance for the help!

```
void getFrame()
{
    //wait here?? seems hacky...
    //boost::this_thread::sleep(boost::posix_time::milliseconds(25));   

    int av_read_frame_error = av_read_frame(m_input_format_context, &m_input_packet);           
    if(av_read_frame_error == 0){       
        //DO STUFF - this all works fine when it gets here
    }
    else{               
        //error
        char errorBuf[AV_ERROR_MAX_STRING_SIZE];
        av_make_error_string(errorBuf, AV_ERROR_MAX_STRING_SIZE, av_read_frame_error);
        cout << "FFMPEG Input Stream Exit Code: " << av_read_frame_error << "   Message: " << errorBuf << endl;             
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Incoming frames needs to be handled in a callback function. So the mechanism should be such that a callback gets called whenever there is a new frame. In this way there is no need to manually fine tune the delay.

Disclaimer: I have not used ffmpeg APIs.

Comment: I'd be all for that but I can't seem to find a way to do that in ffmpeg's C API. `av_read_frame()` is _supposed_ to be a blocking function that will repeatedly call an interrupt callback until it finds a frame. I'd think in that case I should be able to call it as frequently as I want. I suspect the real problem is with the mpeg2video errors printed on the console, but I can't find any clues on to what they mean.

Comment: @six6and1one did you finally figure out the issue? I am running into a similar problem.